# How to solve "Cannot read /qtsqldrivers-config.pri:" while building sql drivers for Qt5 for mac users

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

**this is my *mysql.pro* file**

```
TARGET = qsqlmysql

HEADERS += $$PWD/qsql_mysql_p.h
SOURCES += $$PWD/qsql_mysql.cpp $$PWD/main.cpp

QMAKE_USE += mysql


OTHER_FILES += mysql.json

PLUGIN_CLASS_NAME = QMYSQLDriverPlugin
include(../qsqldriverbase.pri)

INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-client/8.0.21/include"

QMAKE_LIBDIR += "/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-client/8.0.21/lib"
```

**The Error**

```
Cannot read /qtsqldrivers-config.pri: No such file or directory
/Users/Lauben/Qt/5.15.0/clang_64/mkspecs/features/qt_plugin.prf:59: Cannot write file /mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_plugin_qsqlmysql.pri: Cannot create parent directory
13:01:35: The process "/Users/Lauben/Qt/5.15.0/clang_64/bin/qmake" exited with code 3.
Error while building/deploying project mysql (kit: Desktop Qt 5.15.0 clang 64bit)
```

When executing step "qmake"

**clang_64 file**

[Clang screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbJ1g.png)

Comment: Are you trying to compile mysql driver on mac?

Comment: Yes
l am trying to compile mysql driver on mac and it is failing.
That's the error it is returning now after it threw this "QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7" error message. so l tried building the libraries myself
It has now taken me more than four days consistently searching stack overflow and other sources but haven't found the solution

Comment: Ok I suggest you read this https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html. I would suggest you compile using the terminal. It's not that difficult

Comment: Yes, the drivers are not there by default (except sqlite).You have to compile it manually. Also remember, before compiling the drivers using the terminal, revert back to the original files.

Comment: l tried installing in the terminal and the problem persists. l think l have to uninstall the whole qt and repeat the whole process again. However l failed to find where to download "libmysqlclient.so" and "my-devel" that are required as stated by the doc.
And l get this when l run "qmake --MYSQL_PREFIX = /usr/local

Comment: l have tried installing in the terminal and the problem still persists. l guess l just have to uninstall Qt and restart all over again. l have also failed to find where to download "libmysqlclient.so" and "mysql devel" as stated by the doc. Thank you for the help

Comment: Dont uninstall the whole qt. Just remove the src folder and download the sources from maintenance tool again. Then try back

Comment: And download this first https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/. This will provide all the .so and devel files

Comment: Thank you so much. l managed to solve it.